# How to wait till Object Searches in Test complete Tool?

Tags: javascript

Im using Testcomplete automation tool.I have written script by querySelector () method.when i was execute the script,if the page loading time become slow,it shows Run time exception

I want to wait till page loads or till objects found.

I have tried delay method.
eX:delay(3000) from this each and every time i need to update delay time.

kindly need helpful.

Comment: Can you be more clear with what you want

Comment: Ex: PageUrl.QuerySelector(".qa-lila-inbox").Click()
  delay(3000)
  PageUrls.QuerySelector(".admin-nav [data-auto-id="adminGroups"]"
)).Click()    I dont want to mention static value in delay method .The page should find Object once the page loaded .

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing this:

- [Wait functions such as WaitWindow, WaitChild, WaitPage, etc](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/56525/)
- Using [FindChild](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/55112/) and Timer

```
   Function WaitForObject(baseObj, timeout) 'timeout in milliseconds'
        props = Array("") 
        vals  = Array("")
        depth = 1 

        startTime = Timer()

        'baseObj would be the object to search from.'
        Set currObj = baseObj.FindChild(props, vals, depth)

        'While(timeout hasnt passed) and (object hasnt been found)'
        While((Timer()-startTime > (timeout/1000)) And (currObj.Exists = False))
            Set currObj = baseObj.FindChild(props, vals, depth)
        WEnd 

        Set WaitForObject = currObj

    End Function
```